# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@material-ui/core/TextField' in a project directory

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

Im using react 18.0 and material ui 5.0 is not supporting that particular version i have tried a lot..still trying

expecting reason for it and proper solution for this problem so that it would be helpfull to troubleshoot such errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The import statement is wrong here and it should be like this

`import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';`

You can refer the official doc here,

`https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field/`